# Should I use multiple tables or one table with more columns when making static copies of rows?

Tags: mysql, database-design

So a user is able to create projects and edit them. All the necessary data for these projects (in progress) is stored in a *projects* table. When the user is happy with the project, they can publish the project. This will create a static copy. They will still be able to edit the project (in progress), but this won't change anything to the copy.

I created another table *published_projects* to store these static copies. This table contains the same columns as the *projects* table plus some extra (e.g. publishing date).

This results in a lot of duplicate content, but it seems unavoidable since changes in projects should not reflect in projects in progress. Is this the best way to do this or is there a better way?

I can combine this to one table, but this would still result in the same number of rows, and I would think that more rows in one table result in slower queries for that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shallow answer says one table.  but...

A single table could work -- you have the column `published_date` (or whatever) to indicate whether this is a frozen copy and it should not be modified except by copying.

I would make the decision on one table versus two based on the complexity of all the supporting code.  Which actions are simpler to write for one versus two?  Or easier to maintain?  Etc.

Given sufficient indexing, performance is not likely to matter.

Also think further on the two-table approach -- are there other columns that can be dropped from each of the two tables?  Be aggressive in answering the question; it may turn out that the two tables are not as similar as you currently thinking.  If so, this would lean the answer toward two tables.